# How can i sort versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'am making an API that returns all the versions currently available. The versions are structured like this: `22.12a`

`22` is the year,`12` is the month and `a` goes up by a letter everytime we launch another version and resets every month.

My problem is that I need to sort the version so that they can be in the release order like this:

`["22.12b","22.12a","22.11a","22.9a"]`

But I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: please add your existing code

Comment: Check the [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/3.3.0/) module.

Comment: That's my problem for now i don't anything really because my problem is that i dont know how to do it or even where to start .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`natsort.natsorted()`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/3.3.0/):

```py
from natsort import natsorted

versions = ['22.12b', '22.12a', '22.11a', '22.9a']

natsorted(versions)

#['22.9a', '22.11a', '22.12a', '22.12b']
```

It can also be done via [`packging.version.parse()`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/stable/version.html#packaging.version.parse):

```
from packaging.version import parse

versions = ['22.12b', '22.12a', '22.11a', '22.9a']

versions.sort(key=parse)

#['22.9a', '22.11a', '22.12a', '22.12b']
```

Comment: Nice find about the `packaging` module, but I would rather go with `from packaging import version` and then use `sort(key=version.parse)` just for the sake of readability and clarity.